# Dictionary Type mismatch in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, dictionary, type-mismatch

The error I'm receiving is: Type mismatch: 'stylesheets'

Stylesheets is defined as:

```
sub stylesheets(collection)
    for each key in collection.Keys
        response.write(stylesheet(key, collection.Item(key)))
    next
end sub

' returns a link tag for each object in the collection
function stylesheet(asset, media_type)
    if (media_type="") then
        media_type="screen"
    end if
    return "<link href=""" & asset_url(asset) & """ type=""text/css"" media=""" _
        &  media_type & """ />"
end function
```

And it is being called as such:

```
<% stylesheets(site_stylesheets) %>
```

Where site_stylesheets has been defined as:

```
' stylesheets is a collection of the stylesheets to be included on all pages
Set site_stylesheets = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
site_stylesheets.Add "css/endoworks.css", "screen"
```

It has been a long time since I've done any VBScript-ing. I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just placing the loop logic from `stylesheets` into the `header` sub[routine]. It works fine now.

@Tester101: I tried your suggestions, but they didn't fix the problem.

Edit: I actually discovered that I had a `stylesheets` argument in the `header` subroutine which is where the `stylesheets` sub was called. So it was trying to execute `nothing` with an argument of site_stylesheets. Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the parenthesis when calling stylesheets. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537819/byref-and-byval-in-vbscript) question for more information.  I don't think you can use parenthesis when calling a sub with only one parameter.

Try this

```
<% stylesheets site_stylesheets %>
```

or this

```
<% call stylesheets(site_stylesheets) %>
```