# Passing variant array to method produces "Type Mismatch" error

Tags: vba

I have the following two methods:

```
Sub Start()
    Dim x As Dictionary
    Set x = New Dictionary
    Call x.Add("first", 1)
    MsgBox TypeName(x.Items) 'Displays "Variant()"
    Call Test(x.Items) 
End Sub

Sub Test(withArray() As Variant)

End Sub
```

My project is referencing "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" to provide the `Dictionary` class used above.  Despite the fact that `x.Items` returns a `Variant()` (as demonstrated by `MsgBox TypeName(x.Items)`, I'm getting the following compile error on `Call Test(x.Items)`:

> Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected

What is wrong?

Note: if I change the `Test` method to:

```
Sub Test(withArray)
    MsgBox TypeName(withArray)
End Sub
```

It succeeds and displays `Variant()`.  Why can't I explicitly declare the argument as a `Variant()` type?

Comment: Nice question and nice [hint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537819/byref-and-byval-in-vbscript) @mehow . I always use `Call` because I can tell at a glance that a routine is being called. And also because the argument list must be enclosed in parenthesis (calling a routine with many arguments without parenthesis and commas is just too odd/off to my eyes). Now I know all the reasons behind the parenthesis, thanks!

Comment: I agree great question and great answer. I will give this a bounty in 2 days

Comment: yeah, where you at @mehow :)

Comment: @AFischbein as promised :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Items` is a `Variant` of undeclared type, which means as far as the compiler is concerned, it could be anything at all at runtime - not necessarily an array. Of course, WE know it will be an array because its part of a dictionary, but it has no declared type (Object Browser shows it to be a function with no return type) so it defaults to Variant. Since the compiler can't guarantee it will be an array at run-time, it doesn't allow the declaration you are attempting in the Test() proc.
At run-time, it becomes an array, so `TypeName()` shows it as `Variant()`

Interestingly, VBA does allow assignment to a variant array, so this works:

```
Sub Start()
    Dim x As Dictionary
    Dim y() As Variant
    Set x = New Dictionary
    Call x.Add("first", 1)
    MsgBox TypeName(x.Items) 'Displays "Variant()"
    y = x.Items ' this is fine
    Call Test(y) 'this works 
End Sub

Sub Test(withArray() As Variant)

End Sub
```