# WScript.CreateObject returns empty when calling a C++ COM dll function

Tags: c++, string, vbscript, com

I have a C++ COM dll project and the following function works fine when called from its COM object in a VB Script file.

```C++
[id(1)] HRESULT ShowMessage([in] BSTR sMessage, BSTR sTitle); //<< .IDL File

STDMETHOD(ShowMessage)(BSTR sMessage, BSTR sTitle); //<< Header File

STDMETHODIMP CFoo::ShowMessage(BSTR sMessage, BSTR sTitle) //<< C++ Source File
{
    MessageBox(0, CString(sMessage), CString(sTitle), 0);
    return S_OK;
}
```

Above function works fine when I call it from VB Script like this:

```VBScript
Dim Test: Set Test = WScript.CreateObject("VbsEvents.dll")
Test.ShowMessage "Hello World!", "Windows Script Host"
```

However, If I declare function like below:

```C++
[id(2)] HRESULT Add([in] int Value1, int Value2, [out] int *ReturnValue); //<< .IDL File

STDMETHOD(Add)(int Value1, int Value2, int *ReturnValue); //<< Header File

STDMETHODIMP CFoo::Add(int Value1, int Value2, int *ReturnValue) //<< C++ Source File
{
    *ReturnValue = Value1 + Value2;
    return S_OK;
}
```

and call it from VB Script like:

```VBScript
Dim Return: Test.Add 1, 2, CInt(Return)
WScript.Echo CStr(Return)
```

I keep getting nothing echoed, and I expect this to echo 3 as result. I can't figure out why this function not working in VB Script.

Any help is appreciated to find what's the reason for this VB Script code to echo nothing.

Comment: Why `[out]` is not working with VB Script? I even tried `Dim Return: Return = Test.Add 1, 2, CInt("")` and `WScript.Echo CStr(Return)`. This even echos nothing! :-(

Comment: Can't VB Script get output values from COM functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is change the IDL signature from this

```
[id(2)] HRESULT Add([in] int Value1, int Value2, [out] int *ReturnValue);
```

to this

```
[id(2)] HRESULT Add([in] int Value1, int Value2, [out, retval] int *ReturnValue);
```

which makes a lot of sense here because it *is* semantically a return value. See the [retval attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367158.aspx) documentation for info on this.

Then you can call it like this in VBScript:

```
ret = Add(1, 2)
```

Otherwise, check this for more on byref in VBScript: [ByRef and ByVal in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537819/byref-and-byval-in-vbscript)