# Making DLL calls with output parameters in Classic ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Struggling with passing parameters to the external third-party DLL, that is supposed to accept one of the parameters as a value to return.

Code:

```
  Dim InputData 
  Dim ReturnData
  Dim PDF417
  Set PDF417 = Server.CreateObject("IDAuto.PDF417")
  DataToEncode = "test data"
  ReturnData = ""
  PDF417.FontEncode (InputData, 0,0,0,0,0,0, ReturnData )
```

This gives an error that parameter type is wrong.

This works, but doesn't return anything, obviously.

```
  PDF417.FontEncode (InputData, 0,0,0,0,0,0, "" )
```

I suspect that all parameters are passed ByVal in Classic ASP (I'm fixing ancient code), so how can an asp page interact with a DLL call that expects one of the parameters to be an output?

---

UPDATE upon feedback from Mark et al:
  Apologies for the delay, the abundance of syntax options is really confusing.

```
  ' does not feed ReturnData with values
  ReturnData = PDF417.FontEncode (InputData, 0,0,0,0,0,0, "")
  ' error: wrong nunber of arguments
  ReturnData = PDF417.FontEncode (InputData, 0,0,0,0,0,0)
  ' Type mismatch 
  PDF417.FontEncode InputData, 0,0,0,0,0,0, ReturnData 
  ' Type mismatch 
  Call PDF417.FontEncode (InputData, 0,0,0,0,0,0, ReturnData)
  ' Type mismatch 
  Dim x(1)
  x(1) = ""
  Call PDF417.FontEncode (InputData, 0,0,0,0,0,0, x(1))

  ' However, this worked in ASP.NET
  Dim ReturnData
  ' the line below is required to work
  ReturnData = ""
  PDF417.FontEncode (InputData, 0,0,0,0,0,0, ReturnData )
  ' ReturnData contains the encrypted value if run as a .aspx script.
```

Comment: All COM dll have an out parameter. VB Syntax `OutParam = Function(Param1)` with Hresults put into the err object. How it looks to a C program `Hresult = Function(Param1, OutParam)`.

Comment: Note C also has set/get properties while VB just uses the property name. Your language suggests API calls but your code suggests COM.

Comment: Try to call without `( )` because enclosing a ByRef argument in parentheses passes it as ByVal, or use `call()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537819/byref-and-byval-in-vbscript

Comment: @user2316116 agree, but that only applies if `FontEncode` is a `Sub` procedure and not a `Function`. If that was the problem you would get the dreaded `Can't use parentheses when calling a Sub` [because the brackets enclose more than one value](https://ericlippert.com/2003/09/15/what-do-you-mean-cannot-use-parentheses/). So in this instance `FontEncode` must be a `Function`.

Comment: `ReturnData = PDF417.FontEncode (InputData, 0,0,0,0,0,0)`

Comment: Added various syntax calls in the UPDATE section.