# VBScript - Type Mismatch Error when trying to use a Sub that passes variable by reference (Writing an HTA to work with SolidWorks)

Tags: vbscript, solidworks

I am writing an HTA to automate some processes in SolidWorks, namely exporting various user-selectable views to PNG and allowing the user to select where these images are being saved. I am writing the script part in VBScript because that is most similar to the Visual Basic API documentation that I have found, and I am not using the built-in macro feature because I wanted a GUI and more user-interaction/configuration. Note: this is my first experience with VBScript so it could just be a simple knowledge error.

My issue relates to getting (and possibly saving) a scene. I have found the ISwScene.GetP2SFileName ([https://help.solidworks.com/2021/English/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks~SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.ISwScene~GetP2SFileName.html](https://help.solidworks.com/2021/English/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks%7ESolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.ISwScene%7EGetP2SFileName.html) , yes I know this is given in Visual Basic not VBScript) method which I thought would solve my current issue, but when used I am getting the type mismatch error. Having looked into the other methods that I am using, a stark difference in declaration is evident. The other methods I am using (GetActiveConfiguration, GetScene, GetPathName, etc.) all have the form:
Function <name.>() As <dataType.>

This differs from GetP2SFileName which has the form:
Sub <name.> ( _ ByRef Val As <dataType.> _ )

Everything else has been functional to this point, so this difference seems to be the root of the issue.

I have tried various ways of declaring my variable, utilizing the Call tag before hand, with and without parenthesis around the variable; but every variation has either led to Type Mismatch, Expected End of Statement, or Object does not support this method. I read through this other question ([ByRef and ByVal in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537819/byref-and-byval-in-vbscript)) and the answers to see if it was applicable but nothing described there seemed to work.

This is the relevant code snippet:

```
<script language="VBScript">
Dim swApp
Dim Part
Dim SceneStore
Dim SceneFile
Dim ConfigStore
...


Sub Window_OnLoad
  ...
  ' Solidworks Setup and Grabbing Important Data
  Set swApp = CreateObject("SldWorks.Application")
  Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
  ' above is known working, below is new additions for preserving scene through process
  Set ConfigStore = Part.GetActiveConfiguration
  Set SceneStore = ConfigStore.GetScene
  ' SceneFile = ""
  SceneStore.GetP2SFileName SceneFile
  ...
End Sub
...
</script>
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. If you know how to save a scene to a specific location in VBA that would also suffice because I could save the current scene in the SolidWorks macro before creating the shell application and launching the HTA.

Thank you

Comment: `ByRef` is not the issue as arguments are passed `ByRef` by default in VBScript `Sub` Procedures.